# How to convert sql query with in clauses into string

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I want to convert the sql statement into string for dynamic use. But I’m having trouble while concatenation

select
col1, col2
from
Table1
Where
Col3 in ( ‘cat’ , ‘dog’ );

I’m unable to figure out how to put quotes and || for the cat and dog

‘select
col1, col2
from
Table1
Where
Col3 in ( ‘||’‘cat’’ ||’, ‘’dog’ ‘||’)’ || Strcond;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use the q-quoting mechanism (see line #6), as it lets you use single quotes *normally* (also, your single quotes look *fancy*; if you planned to copy/paste from e.g. MS Word into your SQL client, that won't work).

Here's an example:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_str varchar2(500);
  3    strcond varchar2(100) := '  and 1 = 1';
  4  begin
  5    l_str := 'select col1, col2 from table1 where col3 in ' ||
  6             q'[('cat', 'dog')]' || strcond;
  7    dbms_output.put_line(l_str);
  8  end;
  9  /
select col1, col2 from table1 where col3 in ('cat', 'dog')  and 1 = 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option it to use bind variables and put in as many bind variables as the maximum size of the `IN` list:

```sql
select col1, col2 from Table1 Where Col3 in ( :a001, :a002, :a003, :a004 )
```

Then:

- you can use the same statement repeatedly and the SQL engine will not have to reparse it (after the first time).
- you do not need to escape quotes in your list values in the dynamic SQL string.
- your code is less vulnerable to SQL injection.

If you want to pass fewer values than the maximum then you can repeat values:

```sql
DECLARE
  sql VARCHAR2(2000) := 'select col1, col2 from Table1 Where Col3 in ( :a001, :a002, :a003, :a004 )';
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql USING 'cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat';
END;
/
```

However, if you are going to do this then you can consider if you can eliminate dynamic SQL entirely:

```sql
DECLARE
  a001 Table1.Col3%TYPE := 'cat';
  a002 Table1.Col3%TYPE := 'dog';
  a003 Table1.Col3%TYPE := a001;
  a004 Table1.Col3%TYPE := a001;

  col1_values SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
  col2_values SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
BEGIN
  select col1, col2
  BULK COLLECT INTO col1_values, col2_values
  from   Table1
  Where Col3 in ( a001, a002, a003, a004 );
END;
/
```